# Chart.JS Arc upside down

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using Chart.JS and pieceLabel at the moment to display information.  I find that setting Arc to true allows for me to show my data in an easier to read format however it makes all of the values on the bottom half of the doughnut chart to be 'upside down'.  Is there a way to make the values be displayed in the same format as when arc is set to false?

For example my settings are:

```js
pieceLabel: {
            render: 'percentage',
            precision: 1,
   position: 'outside',
            arc: true, // this rotates and curves the text in parallel to the circumference
   overlap: true,
        }
```

So I have my values in percentage outside of the doughnut chart but again every value faces inward and id like them to act the same as if arc was false.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried all the values for position??.. `'default', 'border' and 'outside'`

Comment: @RajeevRanjan That doesn't affect what I am trying to change.  Default puts the percentage inside the slices.  I need to still be outside but not all relative to the middle of the pie